# how to change root disk volume of ec2 instance using ruby sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, resize, volume, volumes

I'm trying to specify the root disk volume size on creation of an EC2 instance.  I passed the option

```
:block_device_mappings = [
        {
          :device_name => "/dev/sda1", 
          :ebs => {
            :volume_size => 50,
          }
        }
      ]
```

but when I logged into the instance it didn't seem to have taken the option that I have specified above.  What did I do wrong?

```
[root@ip-172-18-15-69 ~]# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      25677580 13857284  11558168  55% /
none             1864568        0   1864568   0% /dev/shm
```

Comment: BTW, I tried to specified the device name to '/dev/xvda1', but the API didn't like that.

Comment: Does the console show the volume has having the desired size?

Comment: nope, I want it to be 50G, as you can see it's still the default of 25G

Comment: I meant in the Amazon console - console.aws.amazon.com